# Rename equal rows in same column

Tags: python, dataframe

i have this dataframe:

[image]

What i want is too loop over the 'labels' column, and if some label have the same name, i want to change it, by adding a incremental variable. So the result i want is something like this:

```
 clusters            labels
 Cluster 0       price range
 Cluster 1   going cambridge
 Cluster 2  reference number
 Cluster 3  reference number 1
 Cluster 4   going cambridge 1
 Cluster 5      include free
 Cluster 6      british food
 Cluster 7       center town
 Cluster 8          car type
 Cluster 9        need place
 Cluster 10  reference number 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df["labels"] = df["labels"].str.cat(
    df.groupby("labels").cumcount().astype(str).str.replace("0", ""), sep = " "
)
```

output:

```
      clusters              labels
0    Cluster 0        price range 
1    Cluster 1    going cambridge 
2    Cluster 2   reference number 
3    Cluster 3  reference number 1
4    Cluster 4   going cambridge 1
5    Cluster 5       include free 
6    Cluster 6       british food 
7    Cluster 7        center town 
8    Cluster 8           car type 
9    Cluster 9         need place 
10  Cluster 10  reference number 2
```